# Windows 11 RDP over IPSEC issue

Tags: rdp, ipsec, windows-11

We manage a limited number of servers (running different versions of Windows Server) by a limited number of remote clients (running Windows 10) using RDP connections over IPSec (in "transport mode" - no tunneling / VPN) with a simple, but strong, preshared key.

(the question is definitely not about how this solution is better / simpler / easier / more or less secure... than a VPN connection, it's just like this for historical reasons, it works well and the security / complexity ratio suits us well)

My problem is: I'm unable to make this configuration work using Windows 11.

When I reproduce the exact same configuration - everything is set up using the default Windows Defender Firewall / Connection Security Rules interface - the RDP client hangs on "Configuring remote session..." (after having passed the "Initiating remote connection..." step, probably indicating that the IPSEC connection initialized itself correctly) and fails with a time out after a long time.

In this configuration (with IPSEC activated), servers can be ping by the client (and reciprocally) (and the RDP connection can be established with any of the Windows 10 client on any of the servers).

If I disable the IPSEC rules (both at the Windows 11 client and at one of the servers), I can establish the RDP connection without issue (with this particular server).

At first sight, it seems related to an incompatibility between RDP and IPSec under Windows 11 (no DNS resolution, nor firewall rules, nor credential issue seem to be involved)...

Has anyone already experienced a problem like this? I'm slowly running out of options...

Thanks,

Florent

Comment: `I'm slowly running out of options.` like correlating the data from performing a packet capture on both ends?